# Check to see if a SharePoint site exists or not

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

This is my code which checks if a SharePoint site exists or not.

```
string URL = Console.ReadLine();
using (SPSite objSite = new SPSite(URL))
{
    using (SPWeb objWeb = objSite.OpenWeb())
    {
      Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Site Exists: {0}", objWeb.Exists.ToString()));
    }
}
```

However, it doesn't seem to work. The "Exists" property always returns true even if the site/subsite does not exists. I get the same result when the URL is either "http://intranet"  or "http://intranet/sitedoesnotexists".

Am I using this in the correct way?

Thanks

**Edit**

Sorry about the formatting, I was sure that I applied it but I guess I forgot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `SPWeb.Exists` property - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.exists.aspx

EDIT: Also, pople suggest using this overload of `OpenWeb(..)` method which has a "boolean" parameter: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa543519.aspx to ask for exception if there is no such web site. (see it explained here: http://blog.mastykarz.nl/inconvenient-opening-spsite-openweb/)

Comment: I couldn't agree more... in fact I am one of those people who recommend using OpenWeb(..) http://kitmenke.com/blog/2009/06/08/the-danger-in-using-spsiteopenweb/

Comment: perfect, had the same problem.